# Get rsync incremental file count

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I'm writing a sync script which I want to display the correct ETA-Time for a incremental file list.

I was able to get a list of all files from the remote directory, but since rsync only transfairs changed or new files the stats with pv are incorrect.

I need the command to get the incremental file count, hopefuly thats possible.

I used this command to get the full file count:

```
rsync --list-only -r $REMOTE_HOST:$REMOTE_ATTACHMENTS | wc -l
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `-n`/`--dry-run` option to see what it will do?

Comment: Ah, I need to add this option to the real rsync-commandline, not the one mentioned above, right?

Comment: Yes. Experiment: `rsync -vcrt  /SomeDir /Somewhere` to create two identical dirs. Running `rsync -n -vcrt  /SomeDir /Somewhere` again won't list any files. Change something in /Somedir to have a few files copied again. Run `rsync -n -vcrt  /SomeDir /Somewhere` again and it should list only the new files. Check also the `--info` option.